# Is there a way to split a <path> tag into two parts so that you can style them differently? If not, then can I convert PNG into SVG in a site?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG drawing of Giratina (a Pokemon), and I want to color it now. I have the whole thing layed out, although what I want right now is a way to split a `<path>` tag so that you can color them in CSS with different selectors. It should be kind of like a `<span>`, but unlike this, I cannot include a tag for the d attribute of the `<path>`, so I am kind of stuck. I have tried many things, although I don't get how to do it. Here is an example of my code (note that you don't see much yet):

```
<path d="M1225 2386 c-17 -7 -83 -45 -148 -84 -133 -80 -141 -82 -335 -85 -152 -2 -128 10 -217 -112 -23 -33 -65 -85 -92 -116 -47 -53 -49 -59 -63 -150"/>
```

**EDIT:**
But now, I figured there is no way. So, is it possible to somehow break down the paths into multiple? Is there some sort of logic you can use in order for you to be able to split the paths for separate coloring?

I've tried using a path editor, but it doesn't work the way I want, since it just turns the image I put into the editor into an exact image, and I wanted to see if it could be turned into real SVG code.

So, is there a place that translates a PNG, JPG, or whatever into SVG format, without making any black and white, and it's free? I want to know so that I can somehow turn Giratina into a SVG. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use an SVG editor and create each part alone

Comment: Hi, that would be pretty hard, because I would need to basically redo the whole thing. Is there a way to just quickly color something individually? Thanks.

Comment: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/ helps in analyzing a single path.